# Batch file / add file names to command

Tags: windows, batch-file

Looking for a way to run a command, but insert the path/filenames of all mp4 files from the working directory (where the script is run) to the command.

```
vlc.exe c:\path\filename1.mp4 c:\path\filename2.mp4
```

I have the following code, but the "%%~A" is only inserting one path/filename at a time instead of adding every path filename from the folder.

```
set dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b "%dir%\*.*"') do ("C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%%~A" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/abc} --sout-keep --loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

An elementary solution: first try

```
set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1"
dir /b /a:-d "%dir%\*.*"
```

The same result (filenames only) as in:

```
set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d "%dir%\*.*"') do @echo "%%~A"
```

So add full path as follows:

```
set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d "%dir%\*.*"') do @echo "%dir%\%%~A"
```

Eventually, replace `@echo "%dir%\%%~A"` with your command...